# Embedding an eps image into LaTeX

Tags: eps, epstopdf, undefined

I'm having trouble embedding an eps image into a LaTeX document. I tried this with an example image, and it works fine, so I know it has to do with the file path or something? I'm getting an error message of "Undefined control sequence" when I try to compile it. Am I missing a package that deals with some portion of this? My file is in the same folder as the .tex file, and I'm using TexMaker, if that makes a difference:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\begin{document}
\title{Assignment 5}
\author{Katlyn LaFranca}
\maketitle
\date{}

\section{Part 1}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{integralscreenshot.eps}
\caption{This is a screenshot from our assignment on integrals and loops.}
\label{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \integralscreenshot.eps ...aphics[scale=0.2]{\integralscreenshot.eps}

! Undefined control sequence.<write>LaTeX Warning: File `\integralscreenshot.eps' not found\on@line . ...aphics[scale=0.2]{\integralscreenshot.eps}

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...aphics[scale=0.2]{\integralscreenshot.eps}

File `.eps' not found
```

Comment: integralscreenshot.eps Image is missing

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure that you have `{integralscreenshot.eps}` in your real document and not `{\integralscreenshot.eps}`? If you copy the code you have here back into a clean `.tex` file in the same directory as your image, do you still get the same error? I can't really test as I don't have that image. But I can't see how you'd get *that* error from *this* code.

Comment: @Mu30murugans2katgmail Read the error again: that is not what the message says.

Comment: Could somebody please explain why this is down-voted? It is a first time post from a new user with code for a complete minimal document and an exact error message. While it is true that the error message probably can't be reproduced with minimal example code, the post is way beyond the usual standard for first time questions. What do you want? Blood?

Comment: @cfr Kind cfr I absolutely agree with you. Even in other circumstances, but in a more synthetic way, we must welcome and welcome new users. I, too, would like to understand the reason for the negative vote.